# using netlink is it possible to listen whenever multicast group membership is changed for interface

Tags: networking

I want to do some custom actions whenever an app wants to become a part of an multicast group.

As I understand an app becomes a part of multicast by executing the following command sequence:

```
/* use setsockopt() to request that the kernel join a multicast group */
mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr=inet_addr(HELLO_GROUP);
mreq.imr_interface.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
if (setsockopt(fd,IPPROTO_IP,IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,&mreq,sizeof(mreq)) < 0) {
```

Essentially, if any applications attempts to become a part of a multicast group using `IP_ADD_MEMEBERSHIP`, my application should get notified (either via netlink or other mechanism) so that it can do custom actions.

I tried to add the below which does not help at least in case of `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP`, so want to know if it is possible, and if so what would be the options for netlink-filter?

```
struct sockaddr_nl addr;
memset (&addr,0,sizeof(addr));
addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
//addr.nl_groups = RTMGRP_IPV4_IFADDR;
//addr.nl_groups = RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR;
addr.nl_groups = (1 << (RTNLGRP_LINK - 1)) |
                  (1 << (RTNLGRP_NOTIFY -1)) |
                          (1 << (RTNLGRP_IPV4_ROUTE - 1)) |
                          (1 << (RTNLGRP_IPV4_MROUTE - 1)) |
                          (1 << (RTNLGRP_IPV6_ROUTE - 1)) |
                          (1 << (RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR - 1)) |
                          (1 << (RTNLGRP_IPV6_IFADDR -1 ));
if (bind(nls, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1)    perror ("bind failure\n");

nlh = (struct nlmsghdr *)buffer;
while ((len = recv (nls,nlh,4096,0)) > 0)
{
     for (;(NLMSG_OK (nlh, len)) && (nlh->nlmsg_type != NLMSG_DONE); nlh = NLMSG_NEXT(nlh, len))
........
```

Comment: Is there something in particular that is suggesting that you CAN listen for multicast joins? I'm asking because it might lead me in the right direction. I'm running a somewhat unadultered version of your code and I'm only getting address/route notifications. (Which is normal, since that's mostly what you are registering to.) No mcast join notifications. Even if I register to every group in linux/rtnetlink.h I don't get mcast join notifications. So I guess the answer is, at least for Netlink, no?

Comment: Yes,  This is specifically needed when one wants to write a user-space network driver like "DPDK" but not use it's KNI (Kernel Network Interface) Module.

One typical way a user-space network driver is written is to use the "Tun/Tap" interface where the user-space driver opens and sends/recieves packet over this interface.

Since this "Tun/Tap" interface is a standard linux interface, user-programs will use standard tools to configure it and expect that HW is programmed.
This requires that the driver tap all configurations including MEMBERSHIP.